# cs5 building swf for the wrong version

Tags: flash, flash-cs5

Hey folks, I'm pretty new to flash, so maybe I'm missing something.

I'm using CS5 flash professional to build a swf. I have it publishing to flash 8, actionscript 2. but it will only work with browsers that have 10.1+ plugins, no matter what I try.

is there something really obvious that I'm missing?

Edit:

I'm using swfobject.embed. it looks like this:

`swfobject.embedSWF("/foo.swf", "myContent", "400", "300", "9.0.0", "/foo.swf", flashvars);`

Comment: can you include your embedding code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to make sure your project settings are correctly set to compile the swf to be backwards compatible.

Under "publish settings" (file->publish settings... on a mac), click on the "flash" tab at the top, and change the player version to 8. Once you've done this, your swfobject will work just fine, (and is a little more advisable than the answered straight object/embed tag above, as swfobject will generate that for you).

Hope that helps!

Comment: this would not work for me no matter how hard I tried.

ended up sending the fla/as to a friend with cs4 and he did it. you get points for technically correct answer (especially the bit about swfobject..who writes explicit markup anymore? crazy)

Answer (score 0):

use this in your browser

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" width="400" height="300">
  <param name="movie" value="foo.swf" />
  <param name="quality" value="high" />
  <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
  <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
     <embed src="foo.swf"
      quality="high"
      type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
      WMODE="transparent"
      width="400"
      height="300"
      pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"
      allowScriptAccess="always" />
</object>
```